# React item won't remove from array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this code here:

```
const favouriteMovies = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'setMovieToFavourites': return {
      ...state,
      hearted: [...state.hearted, action.movie]
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}

const unlikeMovie = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'unlikeMovie': return {
      ...state,
      hearted: state.hearted.filter(item => item !== action.movie),
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

So the first function `favouriteMovies` adds movies to array and with the second function I want to remove the movie from the `hearted` movies. In the `unlikeMovie` function I get the movieID which equals to the one of the `liked` movies but it won't remove the movie from the `hearted` state. Why it isn't removing ?

Comment: You compare movie objects directly, not their IDs. If object reference changes over time with other updates, that may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: But the `movie` only have value of movie id.

Comment: Have you tried to see what state.hearted.filter(item => item !== action.movie) returns? Maybe move the code and assign the result to a variable to make sure it's doing what you expect. Also, any chance that unlikeMovie isn't the action type that's being created?

Comment: Can you please show some more code? If your action.movie is the id then the returned state should be filtered

Comment: So action.movie is just an id? If so, using automasean's answer below, maybe change item.id !== action.movie

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the dispatch for unlikeMovie ?

Comment: `onUnlikeMovie: (movie) => dispatch(unlikeMovie(movie))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this code ?

```
const movies = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'setMovieToFavourites': return {
      ...state,
      hearted: [...state.hearted, action.movie]
    }

    case 'unlikeMovie': return {
      ...state,
      hearted: state.hearted.filter(item => item !== action.movie),
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}

export default movies;
```

Comment: Wooorks! Thanks!!

Comment: :) Happy for you !

Comment: It;s because there was two seperate functions with initalState ?

Comment: All your requests to unlike a movie are captured with first reducer. the name of it doesn't matter (`favouriteMovies` in your case, `movies` in my case) because redux  search for an action type that match ( `unlikeMovie` in this case). so your requests stop at `default: return state;` of first reducer. Hope it's clear :). upvote if answer and comment help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might need to compare the IDs to filter out the movie in the `unlikeMovie` function.

Hard to tell for sure without knowing more about the structure of the `movie` object but assuming `action.movie` is the same type of object as `item` in your code sample and they both share an ID property of `movieID`, something like this should work:

```js
const unlikeMovie = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'unlikeMovie': return {
      ...state,
      hearted: state.hearted.filter(item => item.movieID !== action.movie.movieID),
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `movie` only have value of movie id. Only numbers

Comment: I see, thanks. Can you confirm with a `console.log` or `debugger` statement that `action.movie` has the value of the ID you're expecting? Just wondering if it has something to do with how the action is being dispatched.

Comment: Console logger: `setMovieToFavourites", movie: 475557` `unlikeMovie", movie: 475557`

Comment: Can you log the hearted array before the filter?

Comment: `favouriteMovies: hearted: (3) [475557, 290859, 420818]`

Comment: hearted.filter(item => item !== 475557) does the trick. Are you sure the default case isn't being returned i.e. unlikeMovie is actually dispatched?

Comment: Can we see how you are calling `unlikeMovie` please?

Comment: `Card.js`: `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onUnlikeMovie: (movie) => dispatch(unlikeMovie(movie))
});`

Comment: When I console.log `state.hearted` in `unlikeMovie` function I get empty array everytime